# List of supported filetypes for vlcj3?

Tags: java, vlcj

How do I get a list of supported filetypes for VLCJ anywhere, using the latest version of vlcj 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With vlcj 3.x, you can get the list of supported file extensions like this:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.filter.AudioFileFilter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.filter.PlayListFileFilter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.filter.SubTitleFileFilter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.filter.VideoFileFilter;

...

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(AudioFileFilter.INSTANCE.getExtensions()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(VideoFileFilter.INSTANCE.getExtensions()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(PlayListFileFilter.INSTANCE.getExtensions()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SubTitleFileFilter.INSTANCE.getExtensions()));
```

Those file filter implementation classes can also be used as filters in a Swing file chooser dialog.

With vlcj 4.x, this has been moved to the separate vlcj-file-filters project: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-file-filters